# Помогите написать регулярное выражение php

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Нужно делать проверку на наличие такого слова в строке - **p(Любое число)**
Например **p3** или **p7**.

Думаю сделать с помощью `preg_match`:

```
if (preg_match('/^p0-9$/', 'fdssdfdsfp9')) { 
   echo "Your url is ok."; 
}
else { 
   echo "Wrong url."; 
}
```

Comment: А что вы уже пробовали сделать? Что именно не получилось?

Comment: @DmitriySimushev `if (preg_match('/^p0-9$/', 'fdssdfdsfp9')) {
                    echo "Your url is ok.";
                } else {
                    echo "Wrong url.";
                }`

Comment: `/^p[0-9]+$/` учите матчасть.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Опишу, в чём проблема.

В выражении [`^p0-9$`](https://regex101.com/r/tK2oB9/1) не хватает квадратных скобок вокруг нуля и девятки и квантификатора: [`^p[0-9]+$`](https://regex101.com/r/tK2oB9/2).

См. [*Символьные классы* в справке по PHP](http://php.net/manual/ru/regexp.reference.character-classes.php#regexp.reference.character-classes):

> Открывающая квадратная скобка объявляет начало символьного класса, завершаемого закрывающей квадратной скобкой... Символьный класс соответствует одиночному символу обрабатываемой строки, причем сам символ должен содержаться в наборе, определяемым классом.

Для нахождения нескольких символов нужен [квантификатор](http://php.net/manual/ru/regexp.reference.repetition.php):

> **Односимвольные квантификаторы**
>   `*` эквивалентен `{0,}`
>   `+` эквивалентен `{1,}`
>   `?` эквивалентен `{0,1}`

Т.е. если надо найти одну или более цифр, используйте `+`.

Альтернативой символьному классу является класс `\d` (любая цифра):

```
if (preg_match('/^p\d+$/', 'fdssdfdsfp9'))
```